# Bash script ignores arguments when in /bin

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, bin

I have this bash script that I can pass up to three arguments to. It works like a charm when I call it from the directory `./script -h` but when I copy the same file to /bin and call it from anywhere with `script -h`, it seems to ignore the arguments passed.

Why? or maybe more importantly:
What can I do do change that?

Comment: are you sure you are invoking bash at the first line of your script? #!/usr/bin/bash

Comment: Also do a `which script` to see if you are invoking the correct one

Comment: The first line was correct but user000001 had the solution! I used the which command and it turned out I still had an old copy of the file in /usr/bin. That was called and the new copy in /bin was ignored. After deleting the old one it now all works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite see how to mark this as the answer now though. Could you re-post it as one?

Answer (score 2):

`script` is a very useful standard utility program which take a copy of your current session (look for a file called `typescript`).  It creates another shell interface, so you probably didn't notice it was running.

When you write a new program, use a naming convention, like `script.sh`.

Edit:

If you don't like using a file suffix (because it looks too much like Windows) then fine, but use some other naming convention which will ensure your script names do not clash with existing commands.  `test` is another favorite, for example.  You can use `type` to check a command, but that only checks your current environment, you might still have a name collision when running from a different username, for example.

Comment: how is that an answer? and why would he do that? it's not windoze.

Comment: It's an answer because it's probably the mentioned `script` (in `/usr/bin`) that's being called, and not the user's script (in `/bin`).

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me. `script` is already a Linux command so the OP is probably getting the builtin command instead of the actual script.

Comment: sorry, I only used to word 'script' to generalize. My actual file is called something else.

Comment: @fortranondebian:  OK, but please learn from this and post actual code next time.  For example, you might have had a space in the filename.